# Need to reload the information of the sharepoint 2007 webpart after a button is clicked from another webpart

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I am new in sharepoint development. I have 2 webparts attached on a page. The first webpart (MyTestingWebpart[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7mHm.jpg)) basically it does only inserting of data and the other webpart (MyTestingWebpart[2]) displays the records from the database. Now my problem is when I try to click on the save button, somehow I don't know how to refresh the webpart that displays the newly inserted record. Is this possible?

I have added a query at the page load event of MyTestingWebPart[2]. Both of the webparts attached are web user controls. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you connect both the Web Parts. Make Web Part 1 the producer, and 2 the consumer.

Note that you do not really need to pass anything from one to another (You may pass the ID of record inserted), but just the producer-consumer connection would ensure that your second web part is refreshed once the first web part inserts any data into the database.

Comment: Hi Madhur Ahuja, thanks but can you please show me how do i do the producer-consumer you are saying. I'm sorry I'm just new in this thing.

Comment: This tutorial would help you. It seems daunting at first but its just the matter of implementing two interfaces. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469765(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get it at first the definitions and implementations are overwhelming but later on as I read it and had tons of trial and error I finally had it worked. I got what you mean I was looking for a producer haha but I'm sure what you mean right there is provider-consumer. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your user control does not get re loaded, so a work around is to call Response.Redirect("URL of the same page where your web parts are placed")

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Response.Redirect somehow is not working for me. I'm not sure if I'm doing the exact redirection, what I did is this after the insert I wrote this line  Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("MyTestWebPart.aspx")); and during post back it maps to the exact url but an error came out saying the page cannot be displayed...  the url looks like this http://moss01:6030/HelpFold/MyTestWebPart.aspx?PageView=Shared exactly the same as the old one.